# freeform add datepicker to text field

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, jquery

I cannot get my datepicker to work in the freeform demo  templates.  I have included the css, jquery and jquery UI.  THe datepicker works on a test page when not in a freeform, but it will not ork once I add it to a freeform

`href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
script type="text/javascript">
    $('#form-input-date').datepicker();
/script
input name="date" type="text" id="form-input-date" class="form-control " maxlength="" placeholder=""`

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the jquery in the inc_footer